# Why is my media query not working?

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

Let me start over, as I clearly didn't post my question correctly.

I have a site with media queries and none of my queries are working. This is a Wordpress site build on the Genesis platform.

Header:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

CSS with query:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 775px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    #header {
        float: none;
    }

    .another_site_inner-wrap {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what else you would need to see to help guide me in the right direction. I'm a bit of a newbie, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Well, no, we cant look at your site, you need to post code. And you clearly need to read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is going to get closed as either unclear, off-topic, or if people are feeling particularly grumpy as spam

Comment: Also [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I guess I shot myself in the foot with this one. If I didn't explain myself well or there is something else I can do to get any assistance, please let me know.

Comment: You might want to also add sensible tags. WordPress for instance. I am not sure if media is appropriate - read the tag wiki and see. But this is much better, retracting down vote. I can't help though.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected the tags.

Comment: It could be that your media query isn't working, but the syntax seems right.  It could also be that your CSS is being overridden somewhere.  Try !important after a style to test it... "float: none !important;" https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 1):

321px is too small try 700px to test it first, if you are trying to change it when you shrink the window then use `max-width`.

Try changing the border and color of a div on a certain with of the page (best way to test and see the media query in action). the media query should work so the problem is how you are implementing it

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  div{
   border-color:red;
   border-width: 10px;
   border-style: solid;
  }
}
```

Read this and play with different querys :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the question, although there really isn't much to it.

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 775px) and (min-width: 1024px) { 
    #header, .another_site_inner-wrap {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

**OPTION 2**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        #header, .another_site_inner-wrap {
            float: none;
        }
}
```

If you want the `#header, .another_site_inner-wrap` to `float: none;` in `1024px` You don't need to re-declare the same `CSS` on `775px`. All `CSS` under `1024px` will be used from `1024px` below.

Comment: What is the URL of the site ? me I know ?

Comment: I managed to get it working using your code. I must have had one small error before my code that was prevent it from being rendered. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Set this at your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. You should explain why he should add this.